# Как узнать какая крутость наклона у неровности что-бы персонаж прошел в зависимости от наклона

Tags: разработка-игр, математика, геометрия

Предположим у нас есть такой мир с холмом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне известно что персонаж (черный прямоугольник) не может поднятся на холм более 50° но как понять что наклон холма больше или меньше 50°?

Comment: В играх подобные расчёты не делаются в реалтайме. Там всё упрощают, и на стадии разработки уровня, известно что на холм зайти можно - добавляется какая нибудь "карта", по которой персонаж "видит" по чему он может ходить. Яркий пример - NavMesh (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigation_mesh) системы.

Comment: Мне кажется вам надо высчитывать угол между персонажем и следующей точкой на холме, на которую персонаж должен шагнуть. Тоесть если угол градусов 40 и меньше (90 градусов - 50 (которые вам нужны) = 40) то персонаж дальше подняться не сможет.

Comment: Интересует именно наклон холма в определенной точке (например, там где он "вырастает" из поверхности) или просто наклон прямой между какой-то точкой на холме и точкой, где находится персонаж?

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо высчитывать угол между персонажем и следующей точкой на холме, на которую персонаж должен шагнуть. Тоесть если угол градусов 40 и меньше (90 градусов - 50 (которые вам нужны) = 40) то персонаж дальше подняться не сможет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красным отмечен угол, который должен быть БОЛЬШЕ 40 градусов [90 максимум :)] (если ограничение на подъем 50 градусов и выше) для того, что-бы персонаж мог подниматься по возвышенности.